# How can I signify the ability to edit something in a table?

Tags: website-design, data-tables

In the below image I have a table where new IDs can be added by clicking the "Add ID" button and then each ID has entries that can be added to it.  It seems confusing to new users but I can't think of a simpler way of doing this.  Any ideas?

To clarify, here is roughly the structure I am trying to provide the users access to:

Pages of IDs that each have a series of one or more "entries" that in turn each has some operating parameters and other data entered by the user.

Currently it is a table where the ID is clickable to access all the entries about that ID and the second two columns are clickable as a unit to access that entry.[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's better to have an explicit "edit mode" that a user engages for 2 reasons:

1. They're explicitly aware that they are making changes to data
2. It's more obvious what data can be manipulated

Answer (score 0):

You will have to grab their attention. So either by putting a blue text with 'edit' somewhere in your row, or simply by displaying a 'edit icon' which may come up when you hover over a row.

[image: Edit Icon]

Answer (score 0):

What might be confusing to users is the wording of "add new ID" and the difference between adding a new ID and adding a new record for an existing ID. ID is a technical term that can represent a number of things. It would be better to specify what this ID represents (user ID, etc).

The context of use is essential to know, so you can provide the best solution:

If I understand well, an ID represents a person. All records for this person should be entered under their specific ID. 
When the users enter data: how do they know if the person has an existing ID or not, do they have easy access to their ID, can they search for a person based on their ID only, or other data?

The ideal workflow I imagine would be something like this:

- search for the person to check if they are already in the system
- if not, "Add new person or user" button
- if yes, "Add new record" button next to the person identification information (ID + actual name and more if available)